# Visual Studio 2012 Linking error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, methods, linker, linker-errors

I'm facing a weird issue here. I have my VS2012 project all set up, working properly. But when i tried the simple task of adding a method to one of my classes, it won't link correctly, i get

`error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Camera::calcularDirecao(class GLFWwindow *)" (?calcularDirecao@Camera@@QAEXPAVGLFWwindow@@@Z)`

Here's my Camera class:

```
class Camera {
public:
    Camera() { ... inline constructor ... }
    ~Camera() {}

    ... other methods ( which link fine ) ...

    void calcularDirecao(GLFWwindow *);
};
```

And in my implementation file i have

```
void Camera::calcularDirecao(GLFWwindow *janela) {
    ... code ...
}

    ... other methods ...
```

I already tried rebuilding and all, with no success. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a (silly) suggestion: In situations like this, when compiler/linker seems to ignore my code, I try adding some *nonsense* into my code to see whether I get a compile error or not! For example, you can just put `lkdhgre` into the body of your `calcularDirecao` method and see whether the compiler complains. If it doesn't, it means that it is not seeing the method body for some reason (wrong file, preprocessor macros, etc.)

Comment: @yzt Yes, i get a compile error when adding garbage to the method

Comment: OK, I'd try changing the name of the method, adding other methods (with implementations in the CPP file) to see whether they'd exhibit the same problem, moving the problematic method's implementation inline, moving it to another CPP file, etc. (Of course these are all steps in the diagnosis, not solutions.)

Comment: @yzt It worked when inlining the method, but there were other methods in the cpp file which worked fine, so i really don't get the reason, but thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 2):

Recreate your project from scratch, check if it works or not. After that compare your `vcxproj` files. They are text files. Any text compare tool will work. Their difference may tell a lot.

Also try to view your source file in a hex editor. Look for any non ASCII symbols in your troubled method and around. Such symbols might be not displayed in the IDE viewer but still may confuse the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that your GLFWwindow definition is getting overridden by some other file included in your .cpp.